# Can wso2am forward request to multiple endpoints?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 api manager (WSO2AM) to manage and publish my APIs. Now, I want to forward a API to multiple endpoint, example: when my product update, I want to notify to many services which are subscribed (store in db).

Can wso2am forward request to multiple endpoints?

Comment: The simple answer to your last question is yes. But your use case is not much clear to give a proper answer.

Comment: There are many services in my project, so, when a CI was updated, I need to call to some services which are config in db, to notify the CI was updated. I want to call to WSO2AM by 1 api, the WSO2AM read the config in DB, and call to multiple endpoints base on config in db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom sequences](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Adding+Mediation+Extensions#AddingMediationExtensions-CreateanduploadmanuallyintheAPIPublisher) for this.

See [this article about services chaining](http://shenavid.blogspot.com/2017/07/service-chaining-with-wso2-api.html) with custom sequences.

Comment: I'm using custom sequences with class mediator, but, we don't want handle call api in class mediator, can we use class mediator to load list of end points and using iterate or foreach to call api by call mediator? how, if yes?

Comment: Why can't you use foreach or iterate inside the sequence instead of class mediator?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a multicast proxy and call multiple endpoint.